# Can I use std::pair as a key in std::multimap?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to use 2 integer numbers as a key in multimap. So I wonder is a structure like

```
std::multimap<std::pair<int, int>, MyClass> M;
M.insert(std::pair<int,int>(X1,Y1), MyClassObject);
```

possible in C++? When compiling I get the following error message:

```
C:\1\1-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK_________\..\main.cpp:199: 
error: no matching function for
call to 'std::multimap<std::pair<int, int>, MyClass, std::less<std::pair<int, int> >,
std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, MyClass> > >::insert(std::pair<int, int>,
MyClass)'
```

Comment: You'd need to implement a comparator for your std::pair type.

Comment: @Nick: why? the default one is ok for most cases, maybe in his case too?

Comment: @Nick `std::pair` is already comparable

Comment: Ah, ok. Sorry for any confusion caused!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

insert takes a pair of key,value, so you need

```
M.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(X1,Y1),MyClassObject));
```